# How to get real name from Google API via Node Client

Tags: javascript, node.js, authentication, authorization, google-signin

My web app allows signing up / signing in with a Google account. I am using the following code to obtain user info from Google:

```
var scopes = ['profile', 'email'];
var url = oauth2Client.generateAuthUrl({ access_type: 'offline', scope: scopes });

router.route('/authorize').post((req, res) => {
  code = req.body.code;
  oauth2Client.getToken(code, (err, tokens) => {
    if (err) return // error handler
    oauth2Client.verifyIdToken(tokens.id_token, clientId, (err, login) => {
      if (err) return // error handler
      console.log(login.getPayload()); // this gives me the JSON object below
    });
  });
});
```

I've tried adding different scopes, but I always just get the same info, which doesn't include the user's real name:

```
{ azp: 'stuffblahblah',
  aud: 'stuffblahblah',
  sub: 'google-id-here',
  email: 'email@address.com',
  email_verified: true,
  at_hash: 'some-hash',
  iss: 'accounts.google.com',
  iat: 1234567890,
  exp: 1234567890 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Despite some documentation suggesting it's possible to get info like real name in the id_token (see https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/backend-auth), I couldn't get it to return that info with the .getToken method. However, I was able to get it by requesting the info in a separate request via the access token:

```
let url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/userinfo?access_token=' + access_token;
request(url, (err, response, body) => {
  if (err) console.log('error');
  console.log(body);
});
```

And the body looks like this:

```
{ 
  "sub": "4319874317893142", 
  "name": "My Real name", 
  "given_name": "My First Name",
  "family_name": "My Last Name",
  "profile": "https://plus.google.com/link_to_my_profile",
  "picture": "https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/link_to_my_pic.jpg",
  "email": "email@address.com",
  "email_verified": true,
  "gender": "male",
  "locale": "en"
}
```

Still wishing there was a way to grab the real name in my initial request, rather than having to make a separate one, but this works well enough.